# How should one interpret the codes for this Rorschach test?

Tags: test

In the short story "Flowers for Algernon" by Daniel Keys, the main character performs a Rorschach test and sees the evaluator code his results as follows:

```
WF+A DdF-Ad orig. WF-A
SF + obj
```

How should one interpret it?

I tried to look up a key for the codes and found things like "W" means that all the segments were used but I don't know what that implies about the person taking the test.

Comment: I'm closing this as too specific to an individual.  There is a coding guide [here](http://fourstarbooks.net/portfolio/trade/rose-03.pdf) that you can try.  My understanding is that this test remains highly controversial, the coding system has changed substantially since this story was written, diagnoses in general should be done by professionals familar with patient details that we don't have, test interpretation requires much training and specialized scoring tools, and this coding is for only 1 card out of 10 (we don't even know which card).